Convergence in subnets
Suppose that $\phi_i$ is a net that is weak* convergent to $\phi$ in a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose $\phi_i$ can be expressed as $a_i\alpha_i + b_i\beta_i$, where $0\leq a_i, b_i \leq 1, a_i + b_i =1$ and $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ belong to disjoint subsets of $H$, $A$ and $B$ respectively. Can we say that there exists a subnet such that  $a_j\alpha_j + b_j\beta_j$ weak* converges to $a\alpha + b\beta$, where $0\leq a, b \leq 1, a + b =1$, and $\alpha \in A, \beta \in B$? If the answer is in the negative, can we impose some extra conditions such that this is true?

This is too broad. What are $A,B$? Are you trying to show that the convex hull $co (A\cup B)$ is weakly closed?

$A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $H$. I am trying to find out that given a net in $co (A \cup B)$ that is weak* convergent to some element in $H$, can I find a subnet that weak* converges to some element in $co (A \cup B)$ ?

That would imply that $co(A \cup B)$ is weakly closed which is not the case. Note that the weak-star topology coincides with the weak topology since $H$ is reflexive.

Instead of a Hilbert space, what happens if we consider $L^\infty(G)$, where $G$ is a locally compact group?

I would assume that things are even worse in that case...

I came across in a paper that if $G_0$ is the set of all irreducible unitary representations of $G$, then this actually holds in $L^\infty (G)$, when we consider $A$ to be $G_0$ and $B$ to be $G_0$ minus a fixed irrreducible unitary representation. I don't know how this can be proved.

If $A$ and $B$ are weakly compact, then this works. For a counterexample in $\mathbb R^2$ consider a line $A$ and a singleton $B={p}$ with $p\notin A$.
